# Meteor Router - how can I detect if current route requires user to be logged in

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router, blaze-html

I'm using Iron router. Some routes of my project require to be rendered only if user is logged in, and some - no matter if user is logged in or not. I tried to `registerHelper` which defines if page `requireLogin` or not, but for some reason even if a route does require login, a wrong section is rendered.

Here's a layout template:

```
<template name="layout">

  {{#if requireLogin}}
    <!-- ... render route content or login form ... -->
      {{#if currentUser}}
        {{> yield}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#unless currentUser}}
        {{> loginPage}}
      {{/unless}}
  {{/if}}

  {{#unless requireLogin}}
    <!-- ... render route content ... -->
    {{> yield}}
  {{/unless}}

</template>
```

Example route pages with `requireLogin` information:

```
<template name="pageUser">
  {{requireLogin true}}
  <!-- ... some user page content ... -->
</template>

<template name="pageTermsOfUse">
  {{requireLogin false}}
  <!-- ... some Terms of use page content ... -->
</template>
```

And Client code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Handlebars.registerHelper("requireLogin", function (requireLogin) {
    console.log(requireLogin)
    return requireLogin;
  });
};
```

A `console.log` should return `true` for User Page, and `false` for Terms of use Page, but instead it logs:

```
undefined
undefined
true
```

Even when `requireLogin` is set to True a section `{{#unless requireLogin}}` is rendered. Any suggestion how to solve this problem may help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the `requireLogin` value somewhere. You can simply use a [session variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session).

```
Template.registerHelper("requireLogin", function (requireLogin) {
  if(requireLogin) Session.set('requireLogin', requireLogin);
  return Session.get('requireLogin');
});
```

Also, I'd use [`Template`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/templates_api) and not `Handlebars`.